# RTesseract not showing the text of images in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ocr, tesseract

I install `RTesseract` in my application but the issue I face is that after reading any image it just give '/f' in output

```
 image =  RTesseract.new('ya.png', lang: 'eng')
 image.to_s
```

Output : `"\f"`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the output is just `"\f"`, that means that tesseract didn't detect any words in the image.